# ImageSpan not showing the image

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to put a small animated image at the end of the paragraph of a custom TextView but it won't show the image when I used the following code:

```
cmptDiag.setSpan(
  ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.diagpause_anim_gif, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
  cmptDiag.length-2,
  cmptDiag.length-1,
  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

I suspect there would be better option for 'context', but couldn't find something that is vaild for it. getContext() doesn't work and I can't put 'this' nor 'this@theCustomTextView'.

Comment: you have to setBounds in your drawable

Comment: a little more hint please? I couldn't find it in the dropdown menu.

Comment: It seems you are using SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE, it will exclude both starting and ending characters. And I think if the length is 0, span is auto removed from the text. You can try to change it to SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE or change this 2 `cmptDiag.length-2,
  cmptDiag.length-1,
 ` to make sure the span length is not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this example.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text = ("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing   and" +
                " typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum   has been the industry's" +
                " standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown" +
                " printer took a galley   of type and scrambled it" +
                " to make a type specimen book.").toSpannable()

        // Get icon from drawable resource
        var icon:Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.cfsuman)

        // Scale bitmap using android kotlin core ktx function
        icon = icon.scale(100,100,false)

        // Image span from drawable icon
        text[49..50] = ImageSpan(this,R.drawable.ic_weekend)

        // Another image span from bitmap
        text[89..90] = ImageSpan(this,icon)

        textView.text = text
    }
}
```

this example will show images in texts.

and if you want to add bound, check this.

```
Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, android.R.drawable.presence_offline);
image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
// Replace blank spaces with image icon
String myText = "myText";
int textLength = myText.length();
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(myText + "   " + "This is another text");
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, textLength, textLength + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

this 'setBound' example writeed by java. but I think you can change to kotlin

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! it seems, in custom views, these codes including mine doesn't work the way it does in activities. I could manage them to work in activities. I think I need to study on it a bit later..